# How do I solve this recurrence of a fibonacci sequence?

Tags: recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

I am attempting to solve this:

> **Problem 4.35.** Solve the following recurrence exactly.
>
> $$T(n)=\begin{cases} a & \text{if } n=0 \text{ or } n=1 \\ T(n-1)+T(n-2)+cn & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
>
> Express your answer as simply as possible using the $\Theta$ notation and the golden ratio $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Note that this is Recurrence 4.1 from Section 4.2.3 if $h(n)=cn$, which represents the time taken by a call on $\operatorname*{Fibrec}(n)$ if we do not count the additions at unit cost. Compare your answer to that of Problem 4.34, in which additions were counted at unit cost.

**Here is my work:**

[image]

Comment: I have edited your question in order to include the picture you provided. However please consider typesetting your question using [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
  T(n) &=U_{n+1}+\beta n+\gamma \\
  &=T(n-1)+T(n-2)+cn \\
  U_{n}+\beta n+\gamma &=
  [U_{n-1}+\beta(n-1)+\gamma]+[U_{n-2}+\beta(n-2)+\gamma]+cn \\
  U_{n} &= U_{n-1}+U_{n-2}+(\beta+c)n+\gamma-3\beta
\end{align*}

Considering
$$
\left \{
  \begin{align*}
    U_{n} &= U_{n-1}+U_{n-2} \\
    \beta+c &= 0 \\
    \gamma -3\beta &= 0
  \end{align*}
\right.$$

Now
$$T(n) = U_{n}-c(n+3)$$

When $n=0$, $a=U_{0}-3c$

When $n=1$, $a=U_{1}-4c$

\begin{align*}
  U_{n} &=
  a\frac{\phi^{n+1}-(-\phi)^{n+1}}{\sqrt{5}}+c[\phi^{n+2}-(-\phi)^{n+2}] \\
  &= aF_{n+1}+cL_{n+2} \\
  T_{n} &= aF_{n+1}+c(L_{n+2}-n-3) \\
\end{align*}

where $F_{n}$ and $L_{n}$ are the Fibonacci and Lucas numbers.